# How do I sort vector of struct container?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct particle {
double x;
double y;
double Th;
double wt;
};
```

I also have a vector `vector<particle> vec`How do I sort the vector `vec` according to increasing data member `wt`I want my vector sorted with increasing `double wt`I thought of using `std::sort` but how do I compensate for the struct?

Comment: You overload the operator< http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: You can pass a comparison function (or object) to `std::sort`, or define `operator<` for your struct. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite easy:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    [](const particle& a, const particle& b) -> bool 
    { 
        return a.wt < b.wt;
    }
```

This sorts the vector, based on the value of `wt`, in increasing order.

You also have another option: Defining `operator<` for `particle`, as follows:

```
bool operator<(const particle& a, const particle& b)
{
    return a.wt < b.wt;
}
```

Then, when calling `std::sort`, you can just do:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

With the code above, [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) will call `operator<` on each pair of `particles`, which now have overloads to compare them as such.

If you noticed, the lambda I used in the beginning is the same as the function overload I used above. This easily illustrates the beauty and flexibility of the STL and C++.

Comment: Nice answer..tagged C and came. Put a reference to `sort` if possible.